# Scale kable table to fit page width

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

How do you format a table in pdf using kable function? Because my output table width exceeds the width of the pdf. Here is an example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
df <- cbind(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[1:5,])
knitr::kable(df)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically adjust LaTeX table width to fit pdf using knitr and Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507191/automatically-adjust-latex-table-width-to-fit-pdf-using-knitr-and-rstudio)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One option is to use `kable_styling` from the `kableExtra` package. The option `latex_options="scale_down"` will fit the table within the paper margins. See [the vignette](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) for detailed examples on all of the formatting options.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
kable(cbind(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[1:5,]))
```

```{r}
kable(cbind(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[1:5,]), format="latex", booktabs=TRUE) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi, why is there an error when I try to the code into pdf. pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Model_v101A_Validation_NewTables_v7.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identi

Comment: You haven't provided a reproducible example, so it's difficult to determine what's causing the error.

Comment: Oh I already saw my error. I did not include the r setup. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you explain the purpose of "%>%"? I am new to R.

Comment: It's a "pipe" operator. It pipes the result of the first function into the second one. Take a look this [`dplyr` tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) to see common use case of pipes for data manipulation in R.

Comment: Hi, this solution works good but makes the figure to move to the top of the page in the output, independently of its original place. How can that be avoided? @eipi10

Comment: Inside `kable_styling` add `hold_position=TRUE`.

Comment: is there a way to just set a margin limit and have the table not extend beyond that limit?

Comment: What if you have so long a text footnote that extends outside the table after `scale_down`? It seems like `scale_down` does not apply to `footnote`.

Answer (score 14):

Note if you are using longtable, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556022) says,

> since longtable doesn't support resizebox, you cannot use the "scale_down" option in latex_options.

However, they suggested using font_size, e.g.,

```
kable(df, "latex", longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 7)
```