# R markdown wrapping big tables at end of page in pdf document

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am using R studio and R markdown (with `knitr`) to create pdf or html report of my results. I have then used function `kable` to make the table look nice on a PDF output or function `htmlTable` of library `expss` for html output. I have created a big table for example like:

`cbind(row.number=1:10,iris[1:10,],iris[1:10,],iris[1:10,]) -> tbl1`

The problem is that this table has too many columns they go outside the width of the paper. Is there a way to wrap the table with one column repeated as first column. Using the table in the example above, the output should be something like:

`row.number Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1           1          5.1         3.5          1.4
2           2          4.9         3.0          1.4
3           3          4.7         3.2          1.3`

`row.number Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length
1           1         0.2  setosa          5.1
2           2         0.2  setosa          4.9
3           3         0.2  setosa          4.7`

`row.number Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2           2         3.0          1.4         0.2
3           3         3.2          1.3         0.2`

To be continued like this. I created this just by hand, I have not solved the problem already :)

I saw here that it is possible to decrease the size to the table, but that is not rely what I was looking for. 
[Automatically adjust LaTeX table width to fit pdf using knitr and Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507191/automatically-adjust-latex-table-width-to-fit-pdf-using-knitr-and-rstudio/21256277)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longtable in a knitr (PDF) document: using xtable (or kable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265676/longtable-in-a-knitr-pdf-document-using-xtable-or-kable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265676/longtable-in-a-knitr-pdf-document-using-xtable-or-kable is similar but not exactly the same.

Comment: How about rotating the table by 90 degrees? Or switching to landscape format for that page?

Comment: I tried rotating, but that was not exactly the look I was looking for. I ended up I ended up copying the data to Excel and played around with the table there. I will leave this open to see if I get more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I may be missing something obvious here but I don't see why you can't set the **rownames** on the table to be your **row.number** column and then just create a loop creating a table for batches of 3 columns.

Doesn't

```
cbind(iris[1:10,],iris[1:10,],iris[1:10,]) -> tbl1
rownames(tbl1) <- 1:10
kable(tbl1[,1:3])
kable(tbl1[,4:7])
kable(tbl1[,8:10])
```

do what you want?

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what you suggest here. I was hoping there was a way to wrap this automatically.